# Factorise: $2a^4 + a^2b^2 + ab^3 + b^4$

Tags: factoring

Factorize : $$2a^4 + a^2b^2 + ab^3 + b^4$$
Here is what I did:

$$a^4+b^4+2a^2b^2+a^4-a^2b^2+ab^3+b^4$$
$$(a^2+b^2)^2+a^2(a^2-b^2)+b^3(a+b)$$
$$(a^2+b^2)^2+a^2(a+b)(a-b)+b^3(a+b)$$
$$(a^2+b^2)^2+(a+b)((a^2(a-b)) +b^3)$$
$$(a^2+b^2)^2+(a+b)(a^3-a^2b+b^3)$$

At this point I don't know what to do and am feeling that my direction is wrong.  Please help me.
( Wolfram alpha says that the answer is $(a^2-a b+b^2) (2 a^2+2 a b+b^2)$ but how? )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Different Hint**

Since your polynomial is homogeneous, this is equivalent to factoring the degree 4 univariate polynomial $2x^4+x^2+x+1.$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

We look for a factorization on the form

$$2a^4 + a^2b^2 + ab^3 + b^4=(2a^2+\alpha ab+b^2)(a^2+\beta ab+b^2)$$

> We find $\alpha=2,\beta=-1$.

Comment: Looks tricky ;-)

Comment: From this hint it was easy to find the values of alpha and beta but my question is how did you realize that the factorization will be like that ? What makes you think that there will be two quadratic factors and not four linear or one linear and three cubic factors ? Would you be able to figure this out if you didn't know this factorization ? If yes , how?

Comment: @AGoogler You  have just to try all the possibilities (which aren't fortunately too much) and with some practice you'll find the form immediately.

Comment: Using **minar's** hint, you can quickly determine (rational root theorem) that there are no linear factors.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

After **minar**:

$2x^4+x^2+x+1= 2x^4+2x+x^2-x+1= 2x(x+1)(x^2-x+1)+x^2-x+1=(2x^2+2x+1)(x^2-x+1) $

Answer (score 0):

Just Simple Factorisation:
$2a^4+a^2b^2+ab^3+b^4$
$=2a^4+2ab^3+a^2b^2−ab^3+b^4$
$=2a(a^3+b^3)+a^2b^2−ab^3+b^4$
$=2a(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)+b^2(a^2-ab+b^2)$
$=(a^2-ab+b^2)(2a^2+2ab+b^2)$